# Weird data skew after loading a parquet file in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, databricks

I am reading some data from cloud storage in parquet format into Spark DataFrame using PySpark (~10 executors and 4-5 cores per executor). The `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` is set before loading so that I could control the size of each partition and in turn # of partitions I could get. After loading in the data, I apply Spark functions/UDFs on the data. So there should be no shuffle happening (join and groupby). I am expecting that each partition has relatively equal partition size after loading in but the reality is the data loaded is very highly skewed.

When looking in YARN, the min, 25%, median, 75% partition size are all 21 B (basically empty partition) while the max partition size is say 100 MB where all rows are loaded.

What I am doing now to solve this skew is to do a `df.repartition()` to evenly distribute it right after loading and it works well. But this introduces one more shuffle of the data which is not ideal.

So the question is why the partitions are so highly skewed by default after loading? Is there a way that I could load them in with relatively even partition size and skip that `df.repartition()` step?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your input source & file format that reading into spark?

Comment: Also share the file sizes of the data that's being read.  If they're highly skewed, it's hard for Spark to read in the data to memory partitions evenly.  As smart_coder mentioned, the file format / compression type is important to understand if the files are splittable by Spark.

Comment: Thx smart_coder and Powers for the reply! We are loading from parquet. The parquet file is saved by another Spark job and we are using the default compression which should be `snappy` when saving a Spark DataFrame. The data size changes a lot and from what I have seen, on small side, 400 MB and on large side, 30 GB and both encounter the same issue.